# C++ - threading has caused strange output

Tags: c++, pthreads

I don't understand why my code is giving me crazy outputs and sometimes segment errors (the code was written by me 08218722 just in case this is checked for plagiarism by my university).

The code is written in [C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++) in [Linux Mint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint) 14 and compiled with

```
g++ -o code.exe code.cpp -lpthread
```

and then run with `./code.exe`.

The code is supposed to generate a random character vector (using only characters a, b, c, d, e, and f) up to 1000000 and then loops through and counts how much of each character it has. This worked fine before I added threading (part of a assignment to test run time between non-thread and threaded). So I create 1000 threads that are told to make 1000 characters to add to the vector. What am I doing wrong here?

Update-
Code still outputting some crazy results - now it does not display chars but some sort of square boxes

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

//Variable Declarations
const int length = 1000000; // length
const int packets = 1000; // packets length
const char chars[6] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'}; // chars to choose
vector<char> charList(length); //vector of random charecter list
int charGroup[6] = {}; //stores char count
pthread_t threads[packets];



//Structure Declarations
struct dataStruct {
    int start;
    int end;
};

//Function Declarations
void *randomLetterGenerator(void * args); // Declaring function

// prints the vector
void outVector(char n)
{
    cout << n;
}

void GroupVector(char n)
{
   charGroup[n] = charGroup[n] + 1;
}

int main(){
        cout << "Creating a Random Char Array" << endl;
        cout << "using only letters ranging between a and f." << endl;
        //srand(time(NULL)); // sets the time seed
        clock_t start = clock();
        for(int i=0;i<length/packets;i++) {
            printf("\rPlease wait...%3d/%3d",i*packets,length);
            //Created in packets
            dataStruct ds;
            ds.start = i * (length/packets);
            ds.end = ds.start + (length/packets);
            pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, randomLetterGenerator, (void *)&ds);
        }

        for(int i=0;i<length/packets;i++) {
            pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
        }

        printf("\n"); //new line

        //prints out the new char list

        for_each(charList.begin(), charList.end(), outVector) ;

        printf("\n"); //new line

        //Counts and places in the correct array
        for_each(charList.begin(), charList.end(), GroupVector) ;

        int total = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            total += charGroup[chars[i]];
            cout << chars[i] << " = " << charGroup[chars[i]] << endl;
        }
        cout << "\nTotal: " << total << endl;
        clock_t ends = clock();
        cout << "Run Time :"
        << (double) (ends - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
         pthread_exit(NULL);    
        return 0;   

}

void * randomLetterGenerator(void * datastruct){
    dataStruct ds = *((dataStruct *) datastruct);
    int start = ds.start;
    int end = ds.end;

     srand( time(NULL) );
    for(unsigned int c=start;c<end;c++){
        int i = (int) (rand() % 6);
        char rchar = chars[i];
        //--pthread_mutex_lock (&mutex);
        charList.at(c)= i;
        //--charList.push_back(rchar);  
        //--pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutex);  
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Most likely because you have no locking. Multiple threads cannot write to a standard container like vector at the same time. When you have a number of threads doing `charList.push_back(rchar);` in your `randomLetterGenerator` function, this is exactly what you are doing. You'll need to surround this code with a `mutex`, e.g.:

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex;

void * randomLetterGenerator(void * datastruct)
{ 
    //Code as before
    //...
    //Lock the mutex
    charList.push_back(rchar);
    //Unlock the mutex
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using the wrong approach here. You need to create a vector that's appropriately sized, then fill the elements into it using element assignment.

Using the vector's `push_back` function won't work and will likely crash your program as it has to modify the vector's internal state, and that isn't thread-safe. If you surrounded it with locking via a mutex it'd work just fine, but then you'd completely toss any benefits to parallelism out the window.

So create a vector that has the required number of entries already (`vector<char> lots_of_chars(length);`) and then use item assignment to assign to each item. Each thread will have to start at a different offset into the vector so they don't stomp on each other.

I would give you the specific code to use to make this work, but this sounds like an assignment, so I think I shall let you work it out for yourself.

There is one other thread safety issue. It may not actually cause any problems here, but you should be aware of it. `rand` is not thread safe. It relies on shared-global state to churn out successive 'random' numbers. Unless you use boost or C++11 there isn't a good option for thread-safe random number generation that I'm aware of. If you have C++11 though, you should be using C++11s build in thread support instead of pthreads.

In this particular case, it's not terribly important that the random number generation actually generate random numbers. So if threads stomp on each other through the random number generator and cause it to repeat states and generate the same sequences of random numbers or whatever, that should be OK. Of course, that's just the most likely outcome. Using `rand` in this non-thread-safe way is actually undefined behavior and anything at all might happen because of it.

Comment: i see so mutex would slow down the runtime but if each thread has its own range it would work ?

Comment: @echrom: Yes, the mutex would, in fact, serialize all access to the `vector`. And since there would be thread switching and mutex overhead it would actually be a lot slower than one thread. But if you just give each thread a range, they don't have to coordinate after they're launched. I think 1000 threads is way too many. You should have the number of threads be slightly more than the available CPUs. There is one other issue which is that `rand` uses global state and isn't thread safe either. I will add something about that to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much i will get to work on my code and report back if it works out

Comment: Hey changed my code but still getting some crazy stuff the updated code is above and dont really understand where im going wrong

Comment: @echrom: You might want to unit test `randomLetterGenerator` outside of a threaded context. It has some errors in it and you will be less distracted by synchronization issues if you make sure it works when there aren't any because there's only a single thread. Also, you have a problem with how you're handling the data passed to the thread. You're passing the address of a local variable into a thread that will live on after that local variable goes away.

Comment: @echrom: When you've gotten it working, I'll show you what I wrote for this using C++11 (the newest version of the C++ standard).